# Linq to Sql Order by inside a group by not working

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have this column in my table.

```
Date
-----
2014-01-15
2014-05-03
.
.
```

I want to run this query using linq to Sql:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(MONTH,date) as dateColumn
FROM 
    [mydatabase].[dbo].[global_currency_entries]
WHERE 
    date >= '2014-01-01' AND date<='2014-12-31'
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(Month,date)
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(MONTH,date)
```

Linq to sql code I am using:

```
var timePeriod = (from gce in db.global_currency_entries
                  where gce.date >= Convert.ToDateTime("2014-01-01") && gce.date <= Convert.ToDateTime("2014-12-31")
                  orderby gce.date.Month 
                  group gce by new {gce.date.Month});
```

`Orderby` is not working above case.

```
foreach (var time in timePeriod)
{
    lblOutput.Text = lblOutput.Text + time.Key + ",";
}
```

I see this output:

```
{ Month = 9 },{ Month = 3 },{ Month = 12 },{ Month = 6 },{ Month = 7 },{ Month = 1 },{ Month = 10 },{ Month = 4 },{ Month = 5 },{ Month = 2 },{ Month = 11 },{ Month = 8 },
```

Comment: You have your group and ordering clauses reversed compared to the SQL version. Why?

Comment: aaa its my mistake,,, I got it now,,

Comment: The right way would be `(from gce in db.global_currency_entries
                              where gce.date >= Convert.ToDateTime("2014-01-01") && gce.date <= Convert.ToDateTime("2014-12-31")
                              select gce.date.Month).GroupBy(p => p).OrderBy(p => p.Key);`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in LinqPad 5 and I was able to get it to work.  I used C# Program in LinqPad.

```
void Main()
{
    List<global_currency_entries> gce = new List<global_currency_entries>();

    DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014, 12, 01);

    gce.Add(new global_currency_entries
    {
        date = dt
    });

    dt = new DateTime(2014, 12, 25);
    gce.Add(new global_currency_entries
    {
        date = dt
    });

    dt = new DateTime(2014, 09, 03);
    gce.Add(new global_currency_entries
    {
        date = dt
    });

    dt = new DateTime(2014, 09, 25);
    gce.Add(new global_currency_entries
    {
        date = dt
    });


    dt = new DateTime(2014, 07, 15);
    gce.Add(new global_currency_entries
    {
        date = dt
    });

    dt = new DateTime(2014, 07, 20);
    gce.Add(new global_currency_entries
    {
        date = dt
    });

    dt = new DateTime(2014, 05, 05);
    gce.Add(new global_currency_entries
    {
        date = dt
    });


    var result = (from x in gce
              where x.date >= Convert.ToDateTime("2014-01-01") && x.date <= Convert.ToDateTime("2014-12-31")
              orderby x.date.Month
              group x by new {x.date.Month}
              //select x
              );       

    foreach (var n in result)
        Console.Write (n.Key + "  |  ");         

}

public class global_currency_entries
{
    public DateTime date {get; set;}
}
```

My results were
{ Month = 5 }  |  { Month = 7 }  |  { Month = 9 }  |  { Month = 12 }  |